# Jython: where is itertools?

Tags: python-import, jython, jython-2.5

In Jython 2.5.3, trying to import itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import product
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name product
```

Yet if you see [this page from Jython docs](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/itertools.html) itertools looks a core part of Jython since 2.3.

What do I need on the syspath to import iterools?

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product, `product` was added in Python 2.6. So I would not expect it to be available in Jython 2.5.

Comment: @mzjn  Is there any reference on how these versions track with each other?  On that Jython doc page I link to, `product()` is listed about halfway down the page. It says, "Available since 2.3"

Comment: The `product` function was not added until 2.6. It says so also on the page that you link to. Jython 2.X is the same language as CPython 2.X. See https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#Is_Jython_the_same_language_as_Python.3F

Comment: @mzjn  It does say that. You have to scroll down to the full description. (Not used to these docs style).  If you post this as the answer, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is not available in Jython 2.5. The function was added in CPython 2.6, and is available in Jython 2.7.

See also https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#Is_Jython_the_same_language_as_Python.3F.